# fdopendir: Permission denied when running updatedb

Tags: permissions, updatedb

I'm trying to index the files on my NAS (It's a TerraMaster F4-210) with the command:

```
updatedb -l 0 -o /home/jake/nas-index.db -U /mnt/nas/
```

After running for a little while it dies with the error:

```
fdopendir: Permission denied
```

No file is created at /home/jake/nas-index.db

It was mounted with the command:

```
mount -t cifs -o "username=jake,password=mypass" //10.0.0.127/jake /mnt/nas/
mount | grep nas
//10.0.0.127/jake on /mnt/nas type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=3.1.1,cache=strict,username=jake,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=10.0.0.127,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,mapposix,rsize=4194304,wsize=4194304,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
```

and my user can read and write to it.  For example I can do:

```
$> cd /mnt/nas
$> ls -al myfile.txt
ls: cannot access 'myfile.txt': No such file or directory
$> touch myfile.txt
$> ls -al myfile.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Feb 24 01:36 myfile.txt*
$> cat myfile.txt
$> echo "foo" >> myfile.txt
$> cat myfile.txt
foo
$> rm myfile.txt
$> ls -al myfile.txt
ls: cannot access 'myfile.txt': No such file or directory
```

So I can create, append, read, and delete the file.

I have even tried running the updatedb command as root.

To make sure I'm not accidentally ignoring the path or filesystem, I have commented out everything in /etc/updatedb.conf.

I'm not sure what to try next.

What is going on and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like there is a directory on the NAS, that you are not allowed to read. You might find it with `find /home/jake/tnas-index.db > /dev/null` (`find` will put the error-giving directory on STDERR)

Comment: In your `updatedb` command you refer to `/mnt/tnas`, but in your `mount` you refer to `/mnt/nas`.

Comment: I think I fixed the typos.